# Testing Go http.Request.FormFile?

Tags: go

How do I set the Request.FormFile when trying to test an endpoint?

Partial code:

```
func (a *EP) Endpoint(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    ...

    x, err := strconv.Atoi(r.FormValue("x"))
    if err != nil {
        a.ren.Text(w, http.StatusInternalServerError, err.Error())
        return
    }

    f, fh, err := r.FormFile("y")
    if err != nil {
        a.ren.Text(w, http.StatusInternalServerError, err.Error())
        return
    }
    defer f.Close()
    ...
}
```

How do I use the httptest lib to generate a post request that has value that I can get in FormFile?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/mattetti/5914158/f4d1393d83ebedc682a3c8e7bdc6b49670083b84 this gist and my comment https://gist.github.com/mattetti/5914158/f4d1393d83ebedc682a3c8e7bdc6b49670083b84#gistcomment-2301443

Answer (score 22):

You don't need to mock the complete FormFile struct as suggested by the other answer. The `mime/multipart` package implements a Writer type that lets you create a FormFile. From [the docs](https://golang.org/pkg/mime/multipart/#Writer.CreateFormFile)

> CreateFormFile is a convenience wrapper around CreatePart. It creates
> a new form-data header with the provided field name and file name.

```
func (w *Writer) CreateFormFile(fieldname, filename string) (io.Writer, error)
```

Then, you can pass this io.Writer to `httptest.NewRequest`, which accepts a reader as an argument.

```
request := httptest.NewRequest("POST", "/", myReader)
```

To do this, you can either write the FormFile to an io.ReaderWriter buffer or use an io.Pipe. Here is a complete example that makes use of pipes:

```
func TestUploadImage(t *testing.T) {
    // Set up a pipe to avoid buffering
    pr, pw := io.Pipe()
    // This writer is going to transform 
    // what we pass to it to multipart form data
    // and write it to our io.Pipe
    writer := multipart.NewWriter(pw)

    go func() {
        defer writer.Close()
        // We create the form data field 'fileupload'
        // which returns another writer to write the actual file 
        part, err := writer.CreateFormFile("fileupload", "someimg.png")
        if err != nil {
            t.Error(err)
        }

        // https://yourbasic.org/golang/create-image/
        img := createImage()

        // Encode() takes an io.Writer.
        // We pass the multipart field
        // 'fileupload' that we defined
        // earlier which, in turn, writes
        // to our io.Pipe
        err = png.Encode(part, img)
        if err != nil {
            t.Error(err)
        }
    }()

    // We read from the pipe which receives data
    // from the multipart writer, which, in turn,
    // receives data from png.Encode().
    // We have 3 chained writers!
    request := httptest.NewRequest("POST", "/", pr)
    request.Header.Add("Content-Type", writer.FormDataContentType())

    response := httptest.NewRecorder()
    handler := UploadFileHandler()
    handler.ServeHTTP(response, request)

    t.Log("It should respond with an HTTP status code of 200")
    if response.Code != 200 {
        t.Errorf("Expected %s, received %d", 200, response.Code)
    }
    t.Log("It should create a file named 'someimg.png' in uploads folder")
    if _, err := os.Stat("./uploads/someimg.png"); os.IsNotExist(err) {
        t.Error("Expected file ./uploads/someimg.png' to exist")
    }
}
```

This function makes use of the `image` package to generate a file dynamically taking advantage of the fact that you can pass an `io.Writer` to `png.Encode`. In the same vein, you could pass your multipart Writer to generate the bytes in a CSV format (NewWriter in package "encoding/csv"), generating a file on the fly, without needing to read anything from your filesystem.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is great. One thing though, the content-type of the file read through this is "application/octet-stream" instead of the "image/png". Is there a way to get around this?

Answer (score 8):

If you have a look at the implementation of the `FormFile` function you'll see that it reads the exposed `MultipartForm` field.

https://golang.org/src/net/http/request.go?s=39022:39107#L1249

```
        // FormFile returns the first file for the provided form key.
  1258  // FormFile calls ParseMultipartForm and ParseForm if necessary.
  1259  func (r *Request) FormFile(key string) (multipart.File, *multipart.FileHeader, error) {
  1260      if r.MultipartForm == multipartByReader {
  1261          return nil, nil, errors.New("http: multipart handled by MultipartReader")
  1262      }
  1263      if r.MultipartForm == nil {
  1264          err := r.ParseMultipartForm(defaultMaxMemory)
  1265          if err != nil {
  1266              return nil, nil, err
  1267          }
  1268      }
  1269      if r.MultipartForm != nil && r.MultipartForm.File != nil {
  1270          if fhs := r.MultipartForm.File[key]; len(fhs) > 0 {
  1271              f, err := fhs[0].Open()
  1272              return f, fhs[0], err
  1273          }
  1274      }
  1275      return nil, nil, ErrMissingFile
  1276  }
```

In your test you should be able to create a test instance of `multipart.Form` and assign it to your request object - https://golang.org/pkg/mime/multipart/#Form

```
type Form struct {
        Value map[string][]string
        File  map[string][]*FileHeader
}
```

Of course this will require that you use a real filepath which isn't great from a testing perspective. To get around this you could define an interface to read `FormFile` from a request object and pass a mock implementation into your `EP` struct.

Here is a good post with a few examples on how to do this: https://husobee.github.io/golang/testing/unit-test/2015/06/08/golang-unit-testing.html

Answer (score 7):

I combined these and other answers into an [Echo](https://echo.labstack.com/) example without pipes or goroutines:

```golang
func Test_submitFile(t *testing.T) {
    path := "testfile.txt"

    body := new(bytes.Buffer)
    writer := multipart.NewWriter(body)
    part, err := writer.CreateFormFile("object", path)
    assert.NoError(t, err)
    sample, err := os.Open(path)
    assert.NoError(t, err)

    _, err = io.Copy(part, sample)
    assert.NoError(t, err)
    assert.NoError(t, writer.Close())

    e := echo.New()
    req := httptest.NewRequest(http.MethodPost, "/", body)
    req.Header.Set(echo.HeaderContentType, writer.FormDataContentType()) 
    rec := httptest.NewRecorder()
    c := e.NewContext(req, rec)
    c.SetPath("/submit")
    if assert.NoError(t, submitFile(c)) {
        assert.Equal(t, 200, rec.Code)
        assert.Contains(t, rec.Body.String(), path)
        fi, err := os.Stat(expectedPath)
        if os.IsNotExist(err) {
            t.Fatal("Upload file does not exist", expectedPath)
        }
        assert.Equal(t, wantSize, fi.Size())
    }
}
```

Comment: Took good ideas from your solution, thanks. However not everyone uses echo or any other framework.

Answer (score 6):

By combining the previous answers, this worked for me:

```
    filePath := "file.jpg"
    fieldName := "file"
    body := new(bytes.Buffer)

    mw := multipart.NewWriter(body)

    file, err := os.Open(filePath)
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatal(err)
    }

    w, err := mw.CreateFormFile(fieldName, filePath)
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatal(err)
    }

    if _, err := io.Copy(w, file); err != nil {
        t.Fatal(err)
    }

    // close the writer before making the request
    mw.Close()

    req := httptest.NewRequest(http.MethodPost, "/upload", body)
    
    req.Header.Add("Content-Type", mw.FormDataContentType())

    res := httptest.NewRecorder()

    // router is of type http.Handler
    router.ServeHTTP(res, req)
```